# Laravel 5 flash message flashes again after navigating away and using back button

Tags: laravel

In my controller im trying to redirect back with a Flash message in laravel 5. This all works great. The problem is no matter how i set it up the flash message always re-appears if i navigate away and then come back by using the browsers 'back button'.

So i have a users list with a delete button next to each user. When i click the delete button it calls my controller method to destroy. I made a little conditional in there that redirects back with an error if i am trying to delete an owner. I tried the following different ways to redirect back but with all i wind up with the same problem that the message shows again after navigating away and coming back via the browsers 'back button'.

1

```
return Redirect::route('users')->with('error_message', 'Some error msg');
```

2

```
Session::flash('error_message', 'Some error msg');
return Redirect::to('users');
```

In my view i pick it up like this:

```
@if (Session::has('error_message'))
     {{ Session::get('error_message') }}
@endif
```

So that works good, i get the message. But as soon as for example i click a user in my user list to go to the details page and press the browser 'back button', the message flashes again. I dont get why it keeps flashing that data, i was under the impression that it just flashes one time.

Even if i try to clear it right after displaying (like below), it doesnt matter, it will always re-appear?

```
{!! Session::forget('error_message') !!}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, when the user clicks the back button in the browser, the browser tries to display the contents of the previous page without reloading it. So it's likely not Laravel flashing to the session again, but the browser trying to help you out by caching the page for you.

Comment: can you provide any documentation that supports this?

Comment: But why does a flash message appears over and over like that. And more how can i stop it from doing so? I mean it is a very common thing to wind back on a page via the back button so i cant imagine that nobody else has the problem of Flash messages showing again.

Comment: [this](http://blog.55minutes.com/2011/10/how-to-defeat-the-browser-back-button-cache/) is a quick search I found that supports this idea

Comment: Well i could try to stop cache and go that route (thx for the link btw) but it seems to me as with everything in laravel its so perfect, this has to be something other then cache. That would mean that each site that would use Flash messages would have to try to stop all cache and that just sounds off hehe

Comment: This is not correct answer, i have same problem and i need solution not explanation how back button work

Answer (score 8):

Step 1 : create one middleware using following command:

`php artisan make:middleware PreventBackHistory`

Step 2:

replace content of PreventBackHistory.php with following content:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class PreventBackHistory { 

    /*  Handle an incoming request. 
     *  @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *  @param \Closure $next 
     *  @return mixed 
     */ 
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) 
    { 
        $response = $next($request);
        return $response->header('Cache-Control','no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate') 
                        ->header('Pragma','no-cache')                 
                        ->header('Expires','Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'); 
    } 
}
```

step 3: register middleware in kernal.php

`'preventBackHistory' => \App\Http\Middleware\PreventBackHistory::class,`

step 4: use middleware in your controller's construstor

```
public function __construct() 
{ 
    $this->middleware('preventBackHistory');
    $this->middleware('auth'); 
}
```

And good to go :)

Answer (score 4):

For those of you not concerned with back button:

```
@if (Session::has('error_message'))
 {{ Session::get('error_message') }}
 {{ Session::forget('error_message') }}
@endif
```

and if that doesnt make it clear out, try:

```
@if (Session::has('error_message'))
 {{ Session::get('error_message') }}
 {{ Session::forget('error_message') }}
 {{ Session::save() }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You can show flash messages using javascript and use `SessionStorage` to stop repeating messages. Browser cache doesn't know if browser already shown a message, but we can use `SessionStorage` to check it before display.

```
<div id="flash-container"></div>
...

var popupId = "{{ uniqid() }}";

if(sessionStorage) {
   // prevent from showing if it exists in a storage (shown);
   if(!sessionStorage.getItem('shown-' + popupId)) {
      $('#flash-container').append("<div>{{ session('status') }}</div>");
   }
   sessionStorage.setItem('shown-' + popupId, '1');
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this code, please tell me if this works or not?

Comment: Yes, I did. Works great

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across this problem and I think the only way to get around it is to AJAX load your flash messages into the page.

I've not tested this yet but I assume that when the user goes back and the AJAX request fires the previous flash messages will have already been cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems it was indeed the browser cache and after adding the code to stop cache it was ok and the message disappeared. It still is weird to me that i had to add this code to the controller to stop it from caching:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-store, private, no-cache, must-revalidate'); header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, max-stale = 0', false);
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); 
header('Expires: 0', false); 
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header ('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Or this in the htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

But that seemed a bit overkill to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am using Laravel8, And I got same problem.
But all solutions are outdated for latest version.
So, here is the solution for those people who are using Laravel8

```
@if(session('error'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger mb-3">
    {{ session('error') }}
    {{ session()->forget('error') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

`session()->forget('error')` will remove the session named error.
You can also remove multi session data or flash data.
like this - `$request->session()->forget(['done', 'error', 'status']);`