# Laravel 5 flash message keep appearing

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using flash for users feedback after the user successfully (or failed) in creating an article. I'm using PHP version 5.5.27. Here is my store function in controller :

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{

    $data = $request->all();

    Article::create($data);

    Flash::message('Article Created!');

    return redirect ('articles');

}
```

and here is the app.blade.php in my view :

```
<div class="container">

@include('flash::message')

@yield('content')
```

The flash message just keep appearing no matter where I navigate. but if I logged out the user from my app the flash is gone. I've tried using the original Session::message and it's still the same. I've also tried all the solution from [Laravel 5 flash message flashes again after navigating away and using back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038969/laravel-5-flash-message-flashes-again-after-navigating-away-and-using-back-butto) and it still didn't fix my problem.
But when I tried creating a new fresh laravel project it did work nicely. I'm having the TokenMismatchException before this problem and fixing it by editing the VerifyCsrfToken.php file like below :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //return parent::handle($request, $next);

    $response = $next($request);

    if (last(explode('\\',get_class($response))) != 'RedirectResponse') {
        $response->header('P3P', 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
    }

    return $response;

}
```

Is this problem related to VerifyCsrfToken.php file? How can I fix that? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038969/laravel-5-flash-message-flashes-again-after-navigating-away-and-using-back-butto/42823348#42823348

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use this way :

In controller :

```
\Session::flash('key', 'value');
```

In view :

```
@if(\Session::has('key')
 // Include blade file or :
 {{ \Session::get('key') }}
@endif
```

In laravel documentation :

Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next request. You may do so using the flash method. Data stored in the session using this method will only be available during the subsequent HTTP request, and then will be deleted. Flash data is primarily useful for short-lived status messages:

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

Or

```
\Request::session()->flash()
```

Try this way.

Comment: I've already tried that, and the message still keep appearing no matter what until I logged out from the current user and logged in again

Comment: did you tried to use this command : php artisan clear-compiled ? also clear old cache using : php artisan cache:clear

Comment: I've already tried php artisan clear-compiled and it's still the same

Comment: Yes I've also tried what you've mentioned above and it still keep appearing after reload or go to the other pages. But when I tried the flash messaging with a brand new laravel project, the flash msg disappear when I reload or go to the other pages.