# In Laravel ,how to validate all the input fields, display error messages if any, and return back to the form with the inputs if there are errors

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to validate user registration form using Laravel `Validator::make`. The code works, including showing the error messages in the respective fields.
But my problems are :-

**1)** No matter what I type in the email field, ***it always produces an error***. So, it does not ***redirects me to the next page, even if I type the correct format example@example.com*** . I tried removing the "email" validator and tried. It still shows me "email field is required" message

**2)** In addition to that,if there are any errors in one or more fields,the page gets redirected back but the input fields are ***not*** filled up with the past input .

Here is the Controller page

```
public function showdata(Request $request){
    
    $first_name         =   $request->first_name;
    $last_name          =   $request->last_name;
    $email              =   $request->eid;
    $password           =   $request->password;
    $confirm_password   =   $request->confirm_password;
    $mobno              =   $request->mobno;
    $dob                =   $request->dob;
    $gender             =   $request->gender;
    $address            =   $request->address;
    $country            =   $request->country;
    $time               =   $request->dt;
  

 $messages=
         [
    

      'required'                =>   "The :attribute field is required",
      'email.email'             =>    "The :attribute :input format should be example@example.com/.in/.edu/.org....",
       'email.unique'           =>   "The :attribute :input is taken. Please use another email address",
       'confirm_password.same'  =>   "Password and Confirm password fields must match exactly",
       'mobno.digits'           =>    "The :attribute  field accepts only numbers",
       'mobno.digits:10'        =>    "The :attribute should be 10 digits long",
       'dob.date_format'        =>    "The date format :input should be YYYY-MM-DD",
       'address.string'         =>    "The :attribute :input must be in the form of a string"
 
];


$rules = [
      
              'first_name'       =>    'required',
              'last_name'        =>     'required',
               'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
              
              'password'         =>      'required|min:8',
              'confirm_password' =>      'required|min:8|same:password',
              'mobno'            =>    'required|digits:10',
              'dob'              =>      'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d',
              'gender'           =>       'required',
              'address'          =>       'required|string',
              'country'          =>         'required'

  

];

$validate =  Validator::make($request->all(),$rules,$messages);
 

 if($validate->fails()){
    return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validate->messages());
 }
 else{
return view('recheck_form')
->with('first_name',$first_name)
->with('last_name',$last_name)
->with('email',$email)
->with('password',$password)
->with('mobno',$mobno)
->with('dob',$dob)
->with('gender',$gender)
->with('address',$address)
->with('country',$country)
->with('time',$time);
}

}
}
```

And the Blade Page

```
<div class="container pt-2">
<div class="row shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-info rounded text-center text-white">
  <div class="col ">
  
    <h2>New User Registration</h2>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div class="row  m-5 p-5 bg-light  text-info">
     <div class="col">
      <form class="form-group" method="post" action="recheck-form" autocomplete="off">

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  @csrf
 <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name">
  <small class="text-danger">{{$errors->first('first_name') }}</small>
  
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('last_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
 <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name">
  <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</small>
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
 <label for="eid">Email/Username:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="eid">
  <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</small>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
  <small class="text-danger">{{$errors->first('password') }}</small>
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('confirm_password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  <label for="confpwd">Confirm Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password">
  <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('confirm_password') }}</small>
</div>


  <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('mobno') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
 <label for="mobno">Mobile Number:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobno">
  <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('mobno') }}</small>
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('dob') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
 <label for="dob">Date of Birth(in YYYY-MM-DD):</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dob">
  <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('dob') }}</small>
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('gender') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  <label for="gender">Gender:</label>

  <br>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="Female" value="Female">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="Female">
    Female
  </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="Male" value="Male">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="Male">
    Male
  </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 
  <input class="form-check-input " type="radio" name="gender" id="Other" value="Other">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="Other">
    Other
  </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('gender') }}</small>
 </div>


  <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('address') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  <label for="address">Address:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="address"></textarea>
  <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('address') }}</small>
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('country') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
<label for="country">Country:</label>
 <select name="country" class="form-control" id="countrylist">
       <option value disabled selected>Select Country</option>
       
       @foreach($countryname as $key => $country)
       <option id="countryname" value="{{$country->countryname}}">{{$country->countryname}}</option>
        
         @endforeach
      </select>
<small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('country') }}</small>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="dt">Date and Time of Submission:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dt" readonly value=@php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); echo date("Y-m-d,H:i:s ") @endphp>
</div>


<div class="form-group text-center">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
</div>
```

*I dont know how to upload images to Stack Overflow questions. If you can tell me, I can show you the exact problem via images.*

Comment: I would expect `name="eid"` to be `name="email"` as that's what the rule `'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'` will look for. Can you try updating that and  also `$email  =   $request->email;` and try it again?

Comment: Alternatively, you could change the rule to `'eid' => 'required|email|unique:users'`, and the template code to `$errors->has('eid')` and `$errors->first('eid')` but that seems like odd naming to me.

Comment: eid="email/userid"                                                                                                        
 Changing from "eid" to "email" worked last time I tried. But, I still dont understand what was wrong with "eid". Also, if there are any error messages, it shows them,but the inpur fields are without the previous data

Comment: you can add screenshot by clicking on image option on the editor.

Comment: @Asish added answer below with the above and details for showing the previous value on error redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are doing wrong in your code. In the validator rules and messages array, you did write wrong.

Please check the below code It will resolve your issue.

```
    $messages=
         [
      'eid.required'                =>   "The :attribute field is required",
      'eid.email'             =>    "The :attribute :input format should be example@example.com/.in/.edu/.org....",
       'eid.unique'           =>   "The :attribute :input is taken. Please use another email address",
       'confirm_password.same'  =>   "Password and Confirm password fields must match exactly",
       'mobno.digits'           =>    "The :attribute  field accepts only numbers",
       'mobno.digits:10'        =>    "The :attribute should be 10 digits long",
       'dob.date_format'        =>    "The date format :input should be YYYY-MM-DD",
       'address.string'         =>    "The :attribute :input must be in the form of a string"
 
];

    $rules = [
      
              'first_name'       =>    'required',
              'last_name'        =>     'required',
               'eid' => 'required|email|unique:users',
              'password'         =>      'required|min:8',
              'confirm_password' =>      'required|min:8|same:password',
              'mobno'            =>    'required|digits:10',
              'dob'              =>      'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d',
              'gender'           =>       'required',
              'address'          =>       'required|string',
              'country'          =>         'required'
];
```

The page gets redirected back but the input fields are not filled up with the past input.
For this issue you can try the below approach will definitely work

```
$validate =  Validator::make($request->all(),$rules,$messages);
 

if($validate->fails()){
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validate->messages())->withInput();
}
```

And in your input value attribute please write like this **value="{{ old('name') }}"**

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" />
<input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" />
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" />
```

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thank you. But,just since you are here,can you tell me how to make sure the form inputs retain their old data if I click on the back button?

Comment: You need to redirect on this same controller and method again on click of the back button

Comment: @Asish Will you please tell me why this answer is not accepted as best by you.

Answer (score 1):

The names of your field and rules dont match. please update

`"name="eid"` to be `name="email"` as that's what the rule `'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'` will look for.

Then also update `$email  = $request->email;`

In order to reset the previously entered values after the error re-direct, please update your view like this:

In view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
```

---

### Note,

If you want to keep it as `eid`, thats fine too, you just need to make sure everything uses `eid`, ie:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('eid') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
 <label for="eid">Email/Username:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="eid" value="{{ old('eid') }}">
  <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('eid') }}</small>
</div>




$email = $request->eid;


'eid.email' => "The :attribute :input format should be example@example.com/.in/.edu/.org....",
'eid.unique' => "The :attribute :input is taken. Please use another email address",



'eid' => 'required|email|unique:users',
```

Comment: The first part was done. But,I am still getting empty input fields (after redirection with error messages) even after the updated code

Comment: @Asish use `old('email')`

Comment: @AlzafanChristian ah, good catch, I was treating it like a view render, not a redirect :)

Comment: @Wesley Smith Could you explain what that is (view render,etc.) I am basically new to Laravel.

Comment: @Asish Disregard, that, a previous version of my answer suggested sending data to the view as shown [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views) but I forgot that the error case in your code uses a redirect like `back()->withInput()`, Alzafan pointed out my error and that using `old('email')` is the proper way to access those values after a redirect :)

Comment: @Asish I suspect that's a function of your browser caching the html output from the first visit and simply re-displaying it rather than laravel actually setting those values again

Comment: Sorry,my bad. Hitting the back button in the browser doesn't show the input values, but the past error messages of those input fields.

Comment: @Asish see this similar question for why that happens https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038969/laravel-5-flash-message-flashes-again-after-navigating-away-and-using-back-butto